# Objctive-C、C++間で関数コールしたい。

Tags: objective-c

ブリッジヘッダを利用して下記のような感じで、
Objctive-C→C++クラスのメソッドを使用することは確認できました。

> CTest *test = new CTest(); // Objctive-Cクラスで、C++クラスCTestを生成
>   test->test_print();            // C++クラスのメソッド呼び出し（printf()文をいれただけ）

C++クラスから処理終了時にObjctive-Cクラスのメソッドを
コールしてもらうことは可能なのでしょうか。

> test->test_start(callback);　
>   // イメージ： Objctive-Cクラスで、C++クラスのメソッドにObjctive-Cクラスで呼んでもらいたいメソッドを指定

Comment: C++側／ObjC側ソースコードのどちらを改変できるのでしょうか？片方は手を入れられないライブラリとった制約条件はありますか？単純にはObjective-C++としてしまえばC++コードからObjCメソッドを呼び出せると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
特に制約はございません。
＃単純にお勉強中ということもあり、、、

Objective-C++‌​！
すいません、Objective-Cで実施しようとしていました。
試してみます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C++を使えば、どちらも問題なくできます。

以下、簡単なサンプルを書いてみました。
（Xcode 7.2で確認）

#### Objective-Cで書かれたクラス

・ObjectClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
class CppClass;

@interface ObjectClass : NSObject
- (void)testPrint;
- (void)classPrint:(CppClass*)cc;
@end
```

・ObjectClass.mm

```
#import "ObjectClass.h"
#include "CppClass.h"

@implementation ObjectClass
- (void)testPrint {
    NSLog(@"ObjectClass::testPrint()");
}

- (void)classPrint:(CppClass*)cc {

    // Objective-CのなかからC++のメソッドを呼び出し
    cc->testPrint();
}
@end
```

#### C++で書かれたクラス

・CppClass.h

```
#ifndef CppClass_h
#define CppClass_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class ObjectClass;

class CppClass
{
public:
    CppClass();
    ~CppClass();

    void testPrint(void);
    void objectPrint(ObjectClass* oc);
};

#endif /* CppClass_h */
```

・CppClass.mm

```
#include "CppClass.h"
#import "ObjectClass.h"

CppClass::CppClass()
{
}

CppClass::~CppClass()
{
}

void CppClass::testPrint(void)
{
    NSLog(@"CppClass::testPrint()");
}

void CppClass::objectPrint(ObjectClass* oc)
{
    // C++のなかからObjective-Cのメソッドを呼び出し
    [oc testPrint];
}
```

#### 実際の処理

※ViewController.hは省略

・ ViewController.mm

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "ObjectClass.h"
#include "CppClass.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self cppToObjectiveC];
    [self objectiveCToCpp];
}

/// C++のオブジェクトをObjective-Cから使用
- (void)cppToObjectiveC {

    CppClass* cc = new CppClass();

    ObjectClass* oc = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
    [oc classPrint:cc];

    delete cc;
}

/// Objective-CのオブジェクトをC++から使用
- (void)objectiveCToCpp {

    ObjectClass* oc = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];

    CppClass* cc = new CppClass();
    cc->objectPrint(oc);

    delete cc;
}

@end
```

拡張子を.mmにするのさえ忘れなければ、特に問題はないかと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！大変勉強になります。
上記、参考に追加してみたところうまく処理できました。

もう一点お聞きしたいのですが、OSSなどでObjective-Cのクラスを利用した場合、
なぜか、「Unknown type name 'class';did you mean 'Class'?」となり、
mmファイルのhヘッダの部分でエラーとなってしまします。
上記エラーについて下記のような解決策があるとのことで実施してみたのですがうまくいかず…
「Apple LLVM 6.0 - LanguageのCompile Sources AsをObjective-C++に設定」

そもそも、OSSを追加する前は、エラーが出ていない＆上記の設定もしていなかったので、
なぜエラーになるのかがよくわからない状態です。
もしかして、Objective-CとObjective-C++は一緒ににはできないのでしょうか。

Comment: それだけの情報でははっきりとした回答はできません。もうすこし具体的な情報を追加して、別に質問を立てることをおすすめします。ただ、Objective-CとObjective-C++が一緒にできないと言うことはありません。今回の例でも、Objective-CからObjective-C++を使う形になっています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
すいません、別途質問を起こしたいと思います。