# swiftでC++クラスを利用するために、Objective-C++をブリッジヘッダーに追加すると、 「Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?」となりビルドエラーとなる

Tags: objective-c, swift2

swiftでObjective-C++をブリッジヘッダーに追加すると、
「`Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?`」となりビルドエラーとなってしまします。

下記を参考に
C++で書かれたクラス（CppClass.h、CppClass.mm）
Objective-Cで書かれたクラス（ObjectClass.h、ObjectClass.mm）を用意しました。
[Objctive-C、C++間で関数コールしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21123/objctive-c-c%E9%96%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

swiftから利用するため、ブリッジファイルにObjectClass.hを追加したところ、
ObjectClass.hの★箇所で
「`Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?`」と
「`Expected ';' after top level declarator`」のエラーとなってしまいます。

```
class CppClass★
{
public:
    CppClass();
    ~CppClass();

    void testPrint(void);
    void objectPrint(ObjectClass* oc);
};
```

swiftからC++クラスを使用する場合
１：C++クラス→mmファイルにする
２：C++クラスをラップするObjective-C++ファイル・ヘッダーを作成する
３：ブリッジヘッダに「２」のヘッダーを追加する

また、このブリッジヘッダにはほかのOSSのヘッダーもimportしている状態になります。
上記のほか何か必要となる操作はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftからC++のコードは使用できません
Swiftから見えなくなるように隠蔽してください

例えば
ObjectClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjectClass : NSObject
- (void)testPrint;
@end
```

ObjectClass-CppAddtion.h

```
#import "ObjectClass.h"

class CppClass;
@interface ObjectClass (CppAddition)
- (void)classPrint:(CppClass*)cc;
@end
```

のようにC++コードを分離しObjectClass.hをブリッジヘッダに追加します

あるいは、他からの参照がないのであれば ObjectClass-CppAddtion.h は作らずObjectClass-CppAddtion.hの内容を直接ObjectClass.mmに記述してもかまいません

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0
「You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.」
このような記載がありました。すいません。考慮不足でした。
大変勉強になりました。
ご教示いただいた前者の案でさっそく試してみましたが、ビルドも通りました！
のちほど後者も試してみたいと思います。